# Snack Expo Login Error

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been using Snack Expo for some time now, but I can't login with my profile. I have created an expo profile and I can login with it in Expo (website and xde). However, when I try logging in to Snack, I get "Error: cannot log in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the problem was the browser. I was using Microsoft Edge and getting the error. When I tried logging in using another browser (Chrome), everything worked fine!

It also gives an error on Firefox.